# apply general onkeylistener

Tags: android

New to programming, now to android. So I hope I dont annoy you to much.

How would I go about setting an onkeylistener at the top level of the app that captured the keyevent no matter what.

Basically what i have is a linear layout with dynamically added edittexts.
I want to capture the Enter key event and have it get the current edittext, perform some tests then create a new edittext and add it to the layout.

I know I can (and have) implement an onkeylistener to individual child views, but not being a programmer, the logic seems weird to create an edittext that listens for input to create another edittext that listens for input to create another.... (you see where this goes)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
I have lots more info about what Im trying to do, I just dont know what is pertinent and what is not, so let me know if you need more.

Thanks for your time in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29

What you want is to intercept all the events before they are processed by any View in the window. Return true if the event was handled or false if you want the childs to process the event further.

Comment: was able to intercept window event with dispatchKeyEvent like so:`@Override
 public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
         if (event.getKeyCode() == 66) // KeyEvent.* lists all the key codes u pressed
         {   
          // do something on Enter.
         }  
         return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Like Ben said your activity can implement OnKeyListener then for each EditText you create, set the OnKeyListener to be the activity.

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

And then in your implementation of onKey you can handle the key press event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(v == editText1) {
      // do something
    } else if( v == editText2 ) {
      // do something
    }

    return true; // return true if you handled the keypress
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your activity can implement OnKeyListener.

Comment: could i possibly get an example of what that looks like in code?

Comment: so because edittext knows what to do with the Enter key event, it will never get to the onKeyListener implemented by Activity, correct?

Comment: this is incorrect. `Activity` implements `KeyEvent.Callback`. It can respond to events by the onKey* methods, but only to those events that have not been handled previously by any `View`.